# Where can I find online/live and accurate and multi versioned Jersey documentation?

Tags: jersey-2.0

Since java.net has been shut down where can I find an online documentation for Jersey 2.0? Github repo contains docbook only. Docs.oracle.com is a nightmare and does not contains the info I need.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net site closed, not able to access jersey documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976613/java-net-site-closed-not-able-to-access-jersey-documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey 2.23 User Guide is available on the github site: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html