# java.net site closed, not able to access jersey documentation

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

I'm not able to access jersey documentation from, https://jersey.java.net/

Has jersey documentation been moved to a new location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bizarrely it seems that Oracle have pulled the plug on java.net.

The jersey docs are available on the github site:
https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/index.html

Comment: Too bad it's not the latest even though that's what the URL says.

Comment: Good point. It looks like a work in progress so hopefully they'll update it soon. Meanwhile google's cache still works via https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ajersey.java.net%2Fdocumentation%2Flatest%2F

Comment: Now up-to-date, a few broken images still though.

Comment: thanks Minimalis. I've started using jersey 1.19.3 as that's the latest on https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=jersey but couldn't find documentation for the same.

Comment: 2.25.1 is the latest - try here: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.glassfish.jersey.core%22

Comment: 2.x is a glassfish branch, while I've to stick to com.sun.jersey branch for historical reasons and to avoid package change across my application.

Comment: [Here is 1.x](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Jersey issues are available as well 
Issue IDs are same as former JIRA issue IDs ex: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3054 is same as former https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3054

A project migration index is available at https://javaee.github.io